# Classification using by random forest package

Tags: classification

random-forest mtry

I'm doing classification using by random forest package and I have this problem:

> Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtryStart, ntree = ntreeTry,  : 
>     length of response must be the same as predictors

In addition: Warning message:

> In randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtryStart, ntree = ntreeTry,  :
>     The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?

Comment: Can you share the code you ran?

Comment: I used random Forest package